# Use string's fill constructor with an initializer list

Tags: c++, string

I'm reading through [Ivor Horton's "Beginning C++"](http://www.apress.com/9781484200087). In Chapter 7, there's this example on string initialization:

> However, you *can* initialize a string with any number of instances of given character. You can define and initialize a sleepy time `string` object like this:
>
> ```
> string sleeping {6, 'z'};
> ```
>
> The `string` object, `sleeping`, will contain `"zzzzzz"`.  The string length will be 6.

With my compiler, `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)`, the example doesn't work as described. Instead, it works as if I'd given:

```
 string sleeping {"\6z"};
```

Using [`string`'s "from c-string" constructor, rather than its "fill" constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

I know I can use the fill constructor by using parens:

```
 string sleeping(6, 'z');
```

But just to satisfy my curiosity, is there any way to use the fill constructor with an initializer list, as in the book example?

Comment: I can't believe that made it into a book. It's so wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, the standard [specifies it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> - If `T` is an *aggregate type* [...];
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a character array [...];
> - If `T` is an *aggregate type* [...];
> - Otherwise, If the *braced-init-list* is empty [...];
> - Otherwise, the constructors of `T` are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take `std::initializer_list` as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type `std::initializer_list`

So the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::string` that takes an `std::initializer_list` as its first arguments will always be considered before the ones that takes a count and a character.

The only way to use *list-initialization* with this constructor would be to also provide the allocator:

```
std::string s{6, 'z', std::string::allocator_type{}};
```